# Table with variable row height in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tabular, row-height

I am making a GUI in which I want to display some data in a Excel-like table. For some rows there will only be one line of text and for others there will be a number of lines. Hence I want a table where the height of the rows are not the same.

I found this post describing how to make a table with wrapped text using treeview: [Wrap text inside row in tkinter treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131812/wrap-text-inside-row-in-tkinter-treeview)

However, I am not able to change the height of a specific row.

Anyone knows how to do that or know of a better way to make a table like the one described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found some kind of solution to my problem.

Inspired by this post: [tkinter Canvas Scrollbar with Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731784/tkinter-canvas-scrollbar-with-grid). I came up with the following solution. Python is new to me so it could probably be done more elegant:-)

The problem that I am facing now is that the label width is given in text units and wraplength in screen units. Is there a method to find the conversion factor between the two?

```
from tkinter import *
import math
class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        #self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.geometry('950x500+100+100')

        label = Label(self,text='Table with some data', font=("Arial Bold", 25))
        label.pack()

        master_frame = Frame(self, bd=3, relief=RIDGE)
        master_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        # Create a frame for the canvas and scrollbar(s).
        frame2 = Frame(master_frame)
        frame2.pack(side = BOTTOM)

        # Add a canvas in that frame.
        canvas = Canvas(frame2)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Create a vertical scrollbar linked to the canvas.
        vsbar = Scrollbar(frame2, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
        vsbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsbar.set)

        # Create a frame on the canvas to contain the buttons.
        self.table_frame = Frame(canvas)

        #Add some info to table
        newLine = ["Step#","Process Type","Tool Info","Process details","Cost","Comments"]
        self.newRow(0,newLine)
        newLine = ["Step# Step#","Process Type","Tool Info","Process details","Cost","Comments"]
        self.newRow(1,newLine)
        newLine = ["Step# Step# Step#","Process Type","Tool Info","Process details","Cost","Comments"]
        self.newRow(2,newLine)
        newLine = ["Step# Step# Step# Step#","Process Type","Tool Info","Process details","Cost","Comments"]
        self.newRow(3,newLine)
        newLine = ["Step# Step# Step# Step# Step#","Process Type","Tool Info","Process details","Cost","Comments"]
        self.newRow(4,newLine)

        # Create canvas window to hold the buttons_frame.
        canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.table_frame, anchor=NW)

        self.table_frame.update_idletasks()  # Needed to make bbox info available.
        bbox = canvas.bbox(ALL)  # Get bounding box of canvas with Buttons.
        #print('canvas.bbox(tk.ALL): {}'.format(bbox))

        # Define the scrollable region as entire canvas with only the desired
        # number of rows and columns displayed.
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox, width=925, height=200)

    #Add a new line to the table     
    def newRow(self, rowNumber, info2Add):

        numberOfLines = []                  #List to store number of lines needed
        columnWidths = [7,20,20,40,10,30]   #Width of the different columns in the table - unit: text
        stringLength = []                   #Lengt of the strings in the info2Add list

        #Find the length of each element in the info2Add list 
        for item in info2Add:
            stringLength.append(len(item))

        #Find the number of lines needed for each column
        for index, item in enumerate(stringLength):
            #print(math.ceil(item/columnWidths[index]))
            numberOfLines.append(math.ceil(item/columnWidths[index]))

        #Find the maximum number of lines needed
        lineNumber = max(numberOfLines)

        #Define the 6 labels (columns) in each row consist of.                
        col1 = Label(self.table_frame, relief=RIDGE,text=info2Add[0], wraplength=60,bg='white')
        col1.grid(row=rowNumber, column=1, sticky='news')
        col1.config(width=7, height=lineNumber)
        col2 = Label(self.table_frame, relief=RIDGE,text=info2Add[1], wraplength=140,bg='white')
        col2.grid(row=rowNumber, column=2, sticky='news')
        col2.config(width=20, height=lineNumber)
        col3 = Label(self.table_frame, relief=RIDGE,text=info2Add[2], wraplength=140,bg='white')
        col3.grid(row=rowNumber, column=3, sticky='news')
        col3.config(width=20, height=lineNumber)
        col4 = Label(self.table_frame, relief=RIDGE,text=info2Add[3], wraplength=280,bg='white')
        col4.grid(row=rowNumber, column=4, sticky='news')
        col4.config(width=40, height=lineNumber)
        col5 = Label(self.table_frame, relief=RIDGE,text=info2Add[4], wraplength=70,bg='white')
        col5.grid(row=rowNumber, column=5, sticky='news')
        col5.config(width=10, height=lineNumber)
        col6 = Label(self.table_frame, relief=RIDGE,text=info2Add[5], wraplength=210,bg='white')
        col6.grid(row=rowNumber, column=6, sticky='news')
        col6.config(width=30, height=lineNumber)


app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```